# Extending a Django Database dynamically?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am building an app in Django that allows users to add items to their profile, such as previous work experience.  The problem that I am running into is that different users have different amounts of experience.  My current approach is to have a model that looks something like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='modelowner', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    experience1_company = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    experience2_company = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    experience3_company = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    ...
    experience10_company  = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    experience1_title = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    experience2_title = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    experience3_title = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    ...
    experience10_title  = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

In my present model the user can enter up to 10 previous roles, which covers about 95%+ of users.  However, this obviously has the problem where each previous experience a user enters has lots five other attributes (start date, end date, title, description, location). meaning that the model ends up with something like 60 total attributes... and if I need to add something new, I have to add it 10 times.

Question:  Is there a way to dynamically build new model attributes for the users that have more than X number of experiences or is best practice to have each one explicitly defined in the model and just have a practical cutoff (e.g., you can only enter up to 10)?

Comment: A foreignkey is what you need !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to change your model to represent one experience like this:

```
class Experience(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    # and as much other fields as you like:
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Now you can create unlimited `Experience` instances for each user, and fetch them with:

```
user = User.objects.get(username='bob')

Experience.objects.filter(owner=user)
```

or

```
user.experience_set.all()
```

Documentation on this topic is in [Making queries - following relationships "backward"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Comment: Nice answer, however, it doesn't address issue of ordering. The Experience records need to be sorted. If they have some mandatory date, it could be enough, but perhaps a specialized field is a better solution. Also, you could mention performance implications and `prefetch_related`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a model to store work experience information such as(job_title,company_name, start_date, end_date, duties) and link this work experience model to the user profile. something like below:

```
class WorkExperience(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    duties_description = models.CharField(max_length=125)
```

This way, your application can accommodate any number of `WorkExperience` per user